# UILongPressGestureRecognizer on MKAnnotationView not working for single touch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer, mkannotationview

I've been trying to use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in a `MKAnnotationView` subclass. Interestingly the gesture recognizer only triggers when using two ore fingers/touches.

What prevents the gesture recognizer to get triggered with only one touch?

**Implementation**

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                                      action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
pressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.25;
pressRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 0;
pressRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
```

The same implementation in a normal `UIView` shows the expected behaviour working with one touch. Yet it's possible to use `touchesBegan:` and `touchesEnded:` to get a long press gesture working I'm still curious what the reason for this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714174/trouble-using-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-in-custom-mkannotationview) ?

For using my UILongPressGestureRecognizer I disabled AnnotationView and added GestureRecognizer to it:

```
[ann_view setEnabled:NO];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* long_press = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressAnnotationView:)];
long_press.minimumPressDuration = 1.5;
[ann_view addGestureRecognizer:long_press];
[long_press release];
```