# Add long press to annotation pin and not the callout bubble?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am trying to add a long press gesture to the annotation pin.

I can't seem to find a way to add the long press to it though and the only view i can attach it to is the callout view.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does attaching a gesture recognizer to the AnnotationView result in?

Comment: I have added it to the MKAnnotationView and it results in only the callout bubble handling the long press, and not the actual pin

Comment: As I know,annotation pin has a long press gesture to darg it on the map.If possible,override that.(for example,enable dragable and do something in should/will drag).

Comment: what function is that to override?

Answer (score 0):

Annotation pin has a long press gesture to drag it on the map , You have to override the following method :-

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState {

    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding) {
        // custom code when drag ends...

        // tell the annotation view that the drag is done
    } 
    else if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling) 
    {
        // custom code when drag canceled...

        // tell the annotation view that the drag is done
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a gesture recognizer to an annotation instead of the annotation view (the bubble) as long as the annotation view is set to `isEnabled = false`.

This question is a repeat of:
[UILongPressGestureRecognizer on MKAnnotationView not working for single touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021019/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-on-mkannotationview-not-working-for-single-touch)